# command-click broken on Eclipse 3.5/Snow Leopard

Tags: eclipse, macos

Eclipse has a really awesome feature where you can click through a method via ctrl+click (or splat/command-click on OSX). For some reason this is broken for me (I can still access it via F3). I was wondering if anyone had run into a similar issue and might know of a fix?

Comment: This feature didn't work properly in CDT 2.1

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the language supported by your eclipse platform.

As [Secko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127269/secko) mentions in the comments, CDT has issue.
PDT also had problems ([see this list](http://www.eclipse.org/newsportal/article.php?id=2486&group=eclipse.tools.pdt))

But in general, you can try to restart your eclipse with a '`-clean`' option to check if it solves this situation.